# Configuring @IBInspectable Attribute Inspector controls

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, ibdesignable

Is it possible to configure how `@IBInspectable` properties are displayed and/or controlled in the Attribute Inspector?  For example, I have a `CGFloat` property "Overlay Alpha" which shows up in the inspector like this:

[image]

The problem is that the adjustor up/down arrows only update in integral (+/- 1) steps.  I want them to update in small steps, say, +/- 0.05 increments. Is there any way to do that?

How about other properties of the controls?  Can you display a slider for a `CGFloat` instead of a numeric field? Can you add a tooltip?  Can you add static descriptive text?

Just wondering how much I can customize the display.  I'm trying to see how far I can push the IBDesignable feature into making IB an actual UI design tool.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this question?

Comment: No, I never did... 

Comment: Too bad, thanks for posting, though!

Comment: Did you see if using different types had an effect (i.e. `double`, `long`, `float`, `NSInteger`, etc.)?

Comment: Did anyone find any solution?

Comment: Seems like there's no way to achieve this in Xcode (yet). Whatever "type-dance" you make with `@IBInspectable`, Xcode will always render those to *default* controls (eg. color picker for `UIColor`, value adjustors for number based types, etc..).
However, wonder what would happen if you simply type decimal value directly in the filed ? (that works when setting a `NSLayoutConstraint.constant`).

Some references by @Nate Cook and others :
https://gist.github.com/natecook1000/4269059121ec247fbb90,
https://medium.com/anantha-krishnan-k-g/ibdesignable-and-ibinspectable-in-swift-3-702d7dd00ca

Comment: Yeah, kinda looks like Apple hasn't evolved this feature.  I don't think it's changed at all since it was introduced a few years ago.  Workflow-wise, I've abandoned using IBDesignable in the way I described in my original question.  I occasionally use it to tweak the look of things.  But, then I comment out the `@IBDesignable` directive after I'm done.  It's unreliable, a time sink to implement, and severely bogs down Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that the adjustor up/down arrows only update in integral (+/- 1) steps. I want them to update in small steps, say, +/- 0.05 increments. Is there any way to do that?

Lack of any documentation explaining how to do it and the fact that your question is 3+ years old suggest that you can't actually change the increment value of the stepper for your inspectable properties in IB.

What you *can* do, however, is to create another property based on the one you want to adjust, and scale that one so that increments of 1 correspond to steps of the size you want. For example, designers are probably used to thinking about opacity in terms of percentages, so you could create an `alphaPercent` property with getters and setters that scale the `alpha` property up by 100:

```
@IBInspectable var alphaPercent : CGFloat {
    get {
        return self.alpha * 100
    }
    set(percentage) {
        self.alpha = percentage / 100
    }
}
```

If you add that property to an `@IBDesignable` view you'll be able to use the stepper to change the view's opacity by 1% with each click.

> How about other properties of the controls? Can you display a slider for a CGFloat instead of a numeric field? Can you add a tooltip? Can you add static descriptive text?

None of that is currently possible. If you have a long-term need for less technical users to make user interface adjustments (e.g. if you're skinning the same basic app for a number of different customers), it might make sense to build a version of your app that provides an edit mode. Looking at the [Tweaks framework from Facebook](https://github.com/facebook/Tweaks) might give you some ideas.